# A problem in eclipse debugger does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

**When i come to debug some code in eclipse these message appear :**

FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, appending to system class path failed
Unexpected error (103) returned by AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch
Unable to add C:\Users\كمبيوتك\eclipse\jee-2019-122\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\411\0.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar to system class path - the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed

Comment: Please add details for help. Like what steps you took, what have you tried to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your username (and thus the eclipse path) contains non-ASCII symbols in the path.
You should move the eclipse installation folder and project folder out of your user folder (yes, very annoying).
Here you can find more detailed info:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you included a link to a similar article about moving the installation folder and project folders for eclipse (instead of the link for IntellJ IDEA that you included)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the truth is that I don't use IntelliJ nor Eclipse actually and I even didn't noticed the article was IntelliJ specific.